# Equality comparison not working in bash script despite echo showing variables are equal

Tags: bash, comparison

I need to determine that one value set locally in the script matches either one of two values stored on a git repo in a .txt file. I successfully retrieve these values and save them into variables `currentVersion` and `newVersion`. I also do this with `dispGitTime` and `gitMESSAGE`.

What's weird is that these two comparisons are working as expected:

```
if [ "$dispGitTime" = "" ]; then dispGitTime=0; fi
if [ ! "$gitMESSAGE" = "" ]; then clear; echo "$gitMESSAGE"; sleep "$dispGitTime"; fi
```

But these two comparisons are not working! `else` is always being called!

```
if [ "$currentVersion" = "$scriptVersion" ]; then
        upToDate="true"
        printf "\n%*s" $((COLS/2)) "This script is up-to-date!"; sleep 1
    elif [ "$newVersion" = "$scriptVersion" ]; then
        upToDate="true"
        printf "\n%*s" $((COLS/2)) "This script is up-to-date!"; sleep 1
```

The entire function for context:
(see below for output of this function)

```
gitConfigs(){
        terminalPath=""; terminalPath=$(pwd)
        rm -rf ~/upt; mkdir ~/upt; cd ~/upt || return

        # clone repo or update it with git pull if it exists already
        (CMD_gitGet); wait
        cd "$terminalPath" || return

        # get config values from the master branch's properties.txt
        currentVersionLine=$(grep -n "_version " ~/upt/$gitName/properties.txt); currentVersion="${currentVersionLine##* }"; echo $currentVersion
        newVersionLine=$(grep -n "_newVersion " ~/upt/$gitName/properties.txt); newVersion="${newVersionLine##* }"; echo $newVersion
        gitMESSAGELine=$(grep -n "_gitMESSAGE " ~/upt/$gitName/properties.txt); gitMESSAGE="${gitMESSAGELine##* }"
        dispGitTimeLine=$(grep -n "_dispGitTime " ~/upt/$gitName/properties.txt); dispGitTime="${dispGitTimeLine##* }"

        echo $scriptVersion; sleep 2

        # set scriptTitle to match config, else use default
        if scriptTitle=$(grep -n "_scriptTitle " ~/upt/Android-Installer/properties.txt); then
            scriptTitle="${scriptTitle##* }"
        else scriptTitle="$scriptTitleDEF"; fi

        if [ "$currentVersion" = "$scriptVersion" ]; then
            upToDate="true"
            printf "\n%*s" $((COLS/2)) "This script is up-to-date!"; sleep 1
        elif [ "$newVersion" = "$scriptVersion" ]; then
            upToDate="true"
            printf "\n%*s" $((COLS/2)) "This script is up-to-date!"; sleep 1
        else
            upToDate="false"
            printf "\n\n\n\n\n%*s\n" $((COLS/2)) "This script: v$scriptVersion"
            printf "\n%*s\n" $((COLS/2)) "Latest version: v$currentVersion"
            printf "%*s\n" $((COLS/2)) "Version in progress: v$newVersion"

            printf "\n%*s" $((COLS/2)) "Update required..."; sleep 2
            #update
        fi

        # display gitMESSAGE if there is one
        if [ "$dispGitTime" = "" ]; then dispGitTime=0; fi
        if [ ! "$gitMESSAGE" = "" ]; then clear; echo "$gitMESSAGE"; sleep "$dispGitTime"; fi
    }
```

Ouput:

```
1.1.6-beta
1.1.7-release
1.1.7-release





                                            This script: v1.1.7-release

                                           Latest version: v1.1.6-beta
                                   Version in progress: v1.1.7-release

                                                     Update required...
```

Comment: `echo` (or `printf`) is not a reliable way to see the exact value of a variable, because you won't necessarily see spaces at the end, various nonprinting characters, etc. Try using `declare -p varname` to get a much more reliable indication of what's actually in the variables. Oh, and *never* use `echo $varname`; at least double-quote the variable reference (`echo "$varname"`) to avoid a bunch of other possible problems, ambiguities, etc.

Comment: `: not foundall_1.1.7-release.sh: line 185: declare: 1.1.6-beta


: not foundall_1.1.7-release.sh: line 187: declare: 1.1.7-release`

thats what declare -p is returning. do you know what this means?

Comment: Even better, `declare -p varname | cat -v` to see special characters. Smells like `^M` carriage returns!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found using @JohnKugelman 's `declare -p varname | cat -v` suggestion.

There were indeed ^M carriage returns at the end of those variables.

I found the way to remove them here: [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326120/way-to-remove-newline-m-from-variables-only-not-from-file)

Solution? Adding:

```
currentVersion=${currentVersion%$'\r'}

newVersion=${newVersion%$'\r'}
```